# jwpsrv_position event trigger (overrides postMessage)

Tags: jwplayer, jwplayer7

I am experiencing a strange issue and one which did not happen when we were using JW Player v6.
This started after upgrading to JW Player version 7
Firefox and Chrome are showing same behaviour.

A string sent through postMessage from sender to receiver (listener.html, below) should be picked up by a window.eventListener.
postMessage sent a string which looks like this: "{ prop: 'cmi.suspend_data', value: 1567 }"

Instead, this is the event text which is showing in the console:

`10:04:28.905 event data :  listener.html:70:4
10:04:28.905 {"type":"jwpsrv_position","playerId":"myPlayer","rect":{"top":248,"left":25,"width":376,"height":212},"iframeDepth":0,"coords":{"top":354,"left":25},"responseChain":"80632226101"} listener.html:71:4`

The type: `jwpsrv_position` suggests that jwplayer may be sending events which are preventing any others from getting through.
Communication from the listener (on the SCO LMS) to the webinar platform (sender) using postMessage does work

Any ideas will be welcomed, as this is currently a showstopper.

TIA

Neil.

Answer (score 0):

This can be closed off, as although still a mystery as to what the source is of that event, it was actually a red-herring and was distracting me from another area of my code which had an issue in resolving the LMS URL.